# Convert only few JSON fields to API object

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

In the JSON reponse that an API gives me back, i have more than 100 fields, but am interested in only 3 fields. For example, if below is the full JSON response

```
"text": {
        "data": "Click Here",
        "size": 36,
        "style": "bold",
        "name": "text1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 100,
        "alignment": "center",
        "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
    }
```

I want only 3 fields

```
"data": "Click Here",
"size": 36,
"style": "bold"
```

This is my response object in **ArunApi.java** would look like

```java
private String data;
private Integer size;
private String style;
```

When i make a REST Call (below is the snippet), it fails

```java
var response = webClient
                .get()
                .uri(endPoint)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(ArunApi.class)
                .block();
```

Since i have only 3 fields in my API, the conversion isn't happening at all. Please help

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Are you sure the error is caused by the extra fields? can you post the relevant part of the stacktrace? For most json related libraries, extra fields are allowed by default and silently ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate your class with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` if you are using Jackson library. Otherwise, depending on which library you are using, you can search for configuration to ignore fields.

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations

Comment: To give `jsonIgnore`, i have to mention all the 100 fields that am getting from my response and then add `jsonIgnore`.. i want it to happen automatically.. should include only what am having as part of my Api class

Comment: If you read correctly, you need to add `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` on class. This way you don't need to add for all fields with class.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the whole JSON string with GenSON. With the function `parseKeys()` you can get a HashMap that contains all the keys and extract the first three. GenSON is a new library that I created because of problems similar to yours. Link: https://github.com/EvgeniGenchev/GenSON-lib.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use an abstract class with JsonTypeInfo and JsonSubTypes annotations to receive the data and then map with any thing subclass you need. For example:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = RecurringTriggerJsonModel.class, name = "RECURRING"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SimpleTriggerJsonModel.class, name = "SIMPLE"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = CronTriggerJsonModel.class, name = "CRON")
})
public abstract class TaskTriggerJsonModel {

}
```